# Could you please explain this simple general topology theorem?

Tags: general-topology, continuity, intuition, geometric-topology

How to interpret the theorem below? I find this theorem useful for proving other topological stuff (not important here), but generally, I still fail to grasp intuition about such claims.

To be particular: We claim that the mapping $f$ is extendable to closure of $A$ iff the inverse of $f$ separates any disjoint closed subsets of the "image space". Why should I look and say "yes, of course, this is equivalent"? Do you find this intuitive?

[image]
**My thought process:**
I think the inverse images $f^{-1}(B_1)$ and $f^{-1}(B_2)$ must be closed, since closedness is preserved by homeomorphisms (which are all continuous maps of topological spaces I guess). So I don´t get why we are saying *they have disjoint closures* (if they are closed, the closures are the same, or?) instead of simply *they are disjoint*. Also, I still don´t see why this is equivalent of $f$ having extension over the closure of $A$.

**Source**: The theorem is from *Engelking - General Topology*. Can be found online [here](https://fdocuments.in/document/general-topology-by-ryszard-engelking.html).

Comment: You have that $f^{-1}(B_1), f^{-1}(B_2)$ are closed in the topology of $A$ (as $f$ is continuous from $A$ to $Y$), but for the extension you want them to be closed in $X$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To begin: the preimages are closed in $A$, most likely not in $X$.
The point is that if $B_1$ and $B_2$ are closed and disjoint and yet $x$ is in the closure of both preimages then continuous extension becomes impossible, by continuity the image of $x$ under the extension should be in the intersection of $B_1$ and $B_2$ (which is empty). So this condition is definitely necessary.
It is used in the proof of sufficiency to show that every point in $X\setminus A$ has at most one potential value: the intersection $\bigcap\{\overline{f[U\cap A]}:U$ a neighbourhood of $x\}$ is nonempty by compactness and consists of just one point by the condition on the closed sets.

Comment: Im sorry, maybe Im dumb, but why the $x$has to be in the intersection of $B_1$ and $B_2$ if it is in the closure of both preimages? Why cannot it just be mapped to something outside the intersection?
Great answer though, thank you!

Comment: You want to extend $f$ continuously, so if $a_n\to x$ and $b_n\to x$ with $f(a_n)\in G_1,\ f(b_n)\in B_2$, then by continuity and closedness of $B_i$, $f(x)$ would be in both $B_i$.

Comment: Note that I did not say that $x$ itself should be in $B_1\cap B_2$, but its potential image under the extension. The why is explained by @Berci above.